# Changing case in Vim

Tags: vim

Is there a command in Vim that changes the case of the selected text?

Comment: A helpful link I guess: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Switching_case_of_characters

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185235/camelcase-to-underscore-in-vim) for switching between camel case and snake case.

Answer (score 817, accepted):

[Visual select the text](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#visual-use), then <kbd>U</kbd> for uppercase or <kbd>u</kbd> for lowercase. To swap all casing in a visual selection, press <kbd>~</kbd> (tilde).

Without using a visual selection, `gU<motion>` will make the characters in `motion` uppercase, or use `gu<motion>` for lowercase.

For more of these, see Section 3 in [Vim's change.txt](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html) help file.

Comment: In experimenting, it looks like `g~<motion>` works, too. May want to add that, I tend to use `~` exclusively.

Comment: Which means that we can use `gUiw` to turn a word into uppercase. Thanks!

Comment: Or gUw does it.

Comment: @Ilias Karim, not exactly the same! Without the `i` (for inner) you only change from the cursor position to the end of the word, if you use `gUw`.

Comment: Holy ████, it works on greek unicode characters! `Γ`⇔`γ` (I'm using neovim.)

Answer (score 543):

See the following methods:

```
 ~    : Changes the case of current character

 guu  : Change current line from upper to lower.

 gUU  : Change current LINE from lower to upper.

 guw  : Change to end of current WORD from upper to lower.

 guaw : Change all of current WORD to lower.

 gUw  : Change to end of current WORD from lower to upper.

 gUaw : Change all of current WORD to upper.

 g~~  : Invert case to entire line

 g~w  : Invert case to current WORD

 guG  : Change to lowercase until the end of document.

 gU)  : Change until end of sentence to upper case

 gu}  : Change to end of paragraph to lower case

 gU5j : Change 5 lines below to upper case

 gu3k : Change 3 lines above to lower case
```

Comment: In this case, the aw and iw commands would do the same thing since whitespace doesn't have a case. I believe we can save a keystroke and go with the w versions of the command. Is there any reason to use aw here?

Comment: `guw` changes the case from the current position until the end of the word. `guaw` or `guiw` changes the case of the whole word.

Comment: Nice! Just to add that for multiple words, first type the number. For example, change to upper case word at cursor and two subsequent words, 3gUw

Comment: This is ridiculously useful. I am tempted to print it ant stick it on the wall next to my bed.

Answer (score 5):

Additionally, although all is said and its not for visual selection:

There are operators:
Usage: operator motion
See `:h operator` and `:h motion`

Operators can be

```
c   change
d   delete
gu  make lowercase
gU  make uppercase
...
```

The motions are mostly well known:

```
0  first character of the line
$  end of line
aw a word
iw inner word
...
```

So you have to remember just a few operators and the motions (there are much but you will have some favorites).

In this way you get the list of @ungalnanban above.

---

Found on [Vim cheatsheet - devhints.io](https://devhints.io/vim)