# Disable lower case keymap in Vim

Tags: vim

I want do disable change-to-lowercase key map in Vim. Specifically, the command mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2946054/2275286):

> Visual select the text, then `u` for lowercase.

I find out from [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Disable_built-in_command) that I can add `:unmap u` to `.vimrc`, but it will possibly disable undo command, which I don't want.

How can I disable `u` in visual selection mode?

Comment: The `:unmap` will unmap only user-defined mappings, never the builtin commands. See Peter Rincker's answer for the way to solve this

Answer (score 5):

Use `<nop>`:

```
xnoremap u <nop>
```

May also be interested in:

```
xnoremap U <nop>
nnoremap gu <nop>
nnoremap gU <nop>
```

For more help see:

```
:h <Nop>
```