# vi/vim remap or unmap built-in command - the u key in visual mode

Tags: vim, vi

In Visual mode, after selecting text, the <kbd>u</kbd> key will convert the selection to all-lowercase. This is a problem as my `camelCase` text silently gets changed to `lowercase`, and I don't realize that it happened until it's no longer helpful to undo. I want to unmap this behavior, but because it's a built-in command I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Comment: We will be better able to help you if you can show us some sample input, what you have already tried, the current output, and your desired output. In other words, we need to see what you already have, and what you would like to happen instead.

Comment: `vmap u <nop>` Also read `:h map`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable lower case keymap in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49561572/disable-lower-case-keymap-in-vim)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+unmap+u

Answer (score 8):

As it's an internal mapping, you won't be able to `unbind` the combo; however, you can *[remap](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:map-commands)* it to a `<Nop>` so that the keypress does nothing. You can do this with the following command:

```
:map u <Nop>
```

Or, if you want it to apply to visual mode only (recommended, since <kbd>u</kbd> in normal mode is the undo action), you would run this command:

```
:vmap u <Nop>
```

If the above commands produce results you want, you can add one to your `.vimrc` file (usually found in `~/.vimrc`) to make the setting permanent. For additional reading, I would look at [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2092) to look which exact remap option to add.